# Eval expression during compilation and treat runtime errors as compilation errors

Tags: haskell, metaprogramming, template-haskell

I am working on a simple programming language interpreter in Haskell and I have a bit of trouble while defining standard library. I would like it to be defined as a static string at the toplevel and compiled along with my interpreter:

```
stdLibStr :: String
stdLibStr = "id a := a;;"

parse :: String -> Either Error UntypedModule
typecheck :: UntypedModule -> Either Error TypedModule

-- constexpr
stdLib :: TypedModule
stdLib = either (error . show) id $ parse stdLibStr >>= typecheck
```

However, model above won't evaluate `stdLib` during compilation time. Moreover, it won't give me any feedback on neither parsing nor typechecking error. I would like my interpreter simply not compile if either `parse` or `typecheck` returns `Left` as in the following example:

```
stdLibString = "≠²³¢©œęæśð"

-- Compilation error: "cannot parse definition"
stdLib = either (error . show) id $ parse stdLibStr >>= typecheck
```

I was trying to achievie this using `fail` while defining QuasiQuotation for my language, but because of some other problems it is not possible to have such a quotation.

How to do it in most convenient way?

Comment: The tool you are looking for is Template Haskell https://wiki.haskell.org/Template_Haskell in which I am not skilled enough to give a proper answer.

Comment: Why aren't you just defining it as an `Obj` in the first place instead of an `Either Err Obj` value?

Comment: _You_ may be "sure" that the value will always be a `Right`, but how does the compiler know? It sounds like you're looking for dependent types.

Comment: @chepner Because this is just a "metaphore" of a much bigger computation with error handling. I wanted to give a minimal example

Comment: @JezenThomas I am not looking for dependent types, but for a metaprogramming solution

Comment: "Much bigger computation" and "statically defined" is the combination I'm having trouble with.

Comment: @radrow You might want to provide more information about the actual problem. For the minimal example I would just say "don't use an `Either` at all," but I take it this is not the case for the larger program? It is probably better if you give more context, rather than us guessing what that context might be.

Comment: Okay, updating question

Comment: I think your "metaphor" is too simplified. I see what you're going for, but to me this looks a lot like an XY problem, in which case you're definitely better off asking about the actual problem you're having in context.

Comment: Based on your edit, it sounds like you want something like partial evaluation. As @JohnF.Miller said, it does sound like you want Template Haskell. I don't have much experience with it, but maybe [lift](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/7yvb43/ghc_compiletime_evaluation/) is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in comments, Template Haskell is the way to do this.  The function below handles the two cases:

```hs
compileTime :: Lift a => Either String a -> Q Exp
compileTime (Right a) = lift a
compileTime (Left err) = fail err
```

It can be invoked as `$(compileTime (typecheck =<< parse stdLibStr))`.  Or it's short enough to inline as `either fail lift` instead.

To use this, any function called in the `$()` must be defined in a separate module than where it is invoked.

Comment: Could you explain why it must be in different module?

Comment: The [GHC manual](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#template-haskell) explains "Inside a splice you can only call functions defined in imported modules, not functions defined elsewhere in the same module."  A "splice" is the `$()` expression.  I think this simplifies implementation, since GHC can compile one module at a time, as it does without TH.  [This blog post by Ed Yang](http://blog.ezyang.com/2016/07/what-template-haskell-gets-wrong-and-racket-gets-right/) contrasts TH with less restrictive macro systems.